# How can one team "own" another team's first-round pick?

Tags: basketball, terminology, nba, draft

For instance, the byline to [this Bleacher Report article](http://bleacherreport.com/articles/2757817-2018-nba-draft-top-targets-for-whoever-lands-brooklyn-nets-pick) reads "The Cleveland Cavaliers own the Brooklyn Nets' first-round pick in the [2018 NBA draft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_NBA_draft)."

How can one team *own* another team's first-round pick?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Draft picks are an asset, and (in the NBA anyway) they can be traded between teams ([subject to some restrictions](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/16149/what-is-the-ted-stepien-rule)). Whichever team has the pick on the day of the draft gets to select a player and have exclusive rights to that player, independent of which team the pick was originally assigned to - but the original assignment still determines where the pick falls in the order; hence the pick of a losing team like Brooklyn is more valuable than that of a winning team like the Warriors.

In this case, Brooklyn traded the pick to the Celtics as part of the [Kevin Garnett/Paul Pierce trade](https://www.sbnation.com/nba/2013/6/28/4474220/kevin-garnett-paul-pierce-trade-nets-celtics), and the Celtics then further traded that pick to the Cavaliers as part of the [Kyrie Irving/Isaiah Thomas trade](https://www.cbssports.com/nba/news/cavs-celtics-complete-kyrie-irving-isaiah-thomas-trade-boston-adds-pick/).